# iOS 6: Submit to the App Store/UX guidelines changes

Tags: documentation, app-store, ios6

We have build our universal app according to the iOS 5 Appstore and UX guidelines, I am wondering if there is any change in guidelines for iOS 6. Is there any reference where I can check the App Store guidelines changes for iOS6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer: [What’s new in the new Apple App Store Guidelines? - Twisted Blog](http://blog.twistedhq.com/post/31539631405/whats-new-in-the-new-apple-app-store-guidelines)

Comment: Here's a good article explaining about guidelines for Android Google Play and Apple App Store https://www.whatmattered.com/publishing-mobile-apps-on-app-store-google-play/